# The right way to write function and method which do the same in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to understand what is the write way to write a function and class method that do the same. For example, in numpy I can use the `all()` function in 2 ways:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ones(5)
x.all()
np.all(x)
```

A more specific example is as following: suppose I write a module for circles. This module contains the class "Circle", and this class has method called get_area:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    def get_area(self):
        return 3.14 * self.r**2
```

Now, suppose I also want this module to have a function to calculate the area of some circle (independently of the class):

```
def get_area(r):
    return 3.14 * r**2
```

I think this way of writing is redundant. I would write this module as following:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

    def get_area(self):
        return get_area(self.r)

def get_area(r):
    return 3.14 * r**2
```

but I can't find in the internet if this is the right way to do that.
I would be glad to know if this is the right way to do this, or there is a better way that I'm not familiar with.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Normally, you'd put the actual processing in the class, not in an external function. And I think that actually is the way they do in in the numpy library, redundant or not. Have you ever tried to browse through it? That might help.

Comment: Well if you define it in the class you could call it both ways: `c = Circle(r) ; c.get_area() ; Circle.get_area(c)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @User 12692182 I have tried to look at the numpy repository at GitHub, but I didn't understand how to find there the all() function and method.  If you can show me where it is so I could understand how they write it, it will be grate.

Comment: @Tomerikoo actually not. I want just to give the function parameter `r`, independently of the class.

Comment: Then I guess the way you did it above seems pretty fine...

Comment: I found the `all()` function here: numpy\core\fromnumeric.py: line 2325. It looks like it loops back and calls another hidden function, though, so I think your search will not end there.

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import pi

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def get_area(self):
        return pi * self.radius**2
```

Gives:

```
>>> c = Circle(1)
>>>
>>> c.radius
1
>>> c.get_area()
3.141592653589793
>>> Circle.get_area(c)
3.141592653589793
```

As @Tomerikoo said, yours is fine.

As for the source code for the all() function:

- Google 'numpy all'
- [go to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)
- there will be a [button for source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2277-L2351) to the far right of the method definition